# TrigExpand Idiosyncracies

Tags: expression-manipulation, trigonometry

`TrigExpand[Sin[x]^2 Log[y]]` returns `sin^2(x) log(y)`, as one would expect.  However, `TrigExpand[Sin[x]^2 Sin[y]]` unexpectedly (to me, at least) returns `1/2 sin^2(x) sin(y)-1/2 cos^2(x) sin(y)+sin(y)/2`.  This occurs for Mathematica versions 9 and 10.  What am I missing?

By the way, `TrigExpand[Sin[0.2 x]]` converts 0.2 to a complex number, `sin((0.2 +0. I) x)`, which also seems strange.

Comment: What should M have returned for `TrigExpand[Sin[x]^2 Sin[y]]` ?

Comment: `TrigExpand[Sin[0.2 x]] converts 0.2 to a complex number` I think the complex part can from floating point, behind the scene computation since you are using real. But if you do `Chop` on it, it is ok:  `TrigExpand[Sin[0.2 x]] // Chop` gives `Sin[0.2 x]`

Comment: "By the way, TrigExpand[Sin[0.2 x]] converts 0.2 to a complex number..." This functions are defined over the complex plane, so it is natural to make simplifications there. I Think this is not a bug but a feature.

Comment: I assume that somewhere inside TrigExpand the pattern `Sin[_]^2 f_[_]` leads to different transformation rules according to whether `f` is a trig function or not. You have simply found a case where one of those transformations gives a result which a human mathematician would discard as inelegant.

Comment: @Nasser I expected `TrigExpand[Sin[x]^2 Sin[y]]` to return its argument unchanged, `sin^2(x) sin(y)`.

Comment: This question was motivated by the need to expand expressions of the sort, `g = Sin[x]^2 (Sin[.7 (a + b)] + Cos[.3 (c + d)])`.  As explained above, applying `TrigExpand` to the entire expression yields a correct but undesirable result.  I now know that applying `TrigExpand` term-wise solves the problem, `g /. f_[z_] :> TrigExpand[f[z]] // Chop`.