# Why does Mathematica show 4095/4096 terms in TrigExpand?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

```
Clear[x, n];
expr = Cos[x]^(n - 2) (1 - Cos[x]^2 + Sin[x]);
r=TrigExpand[expr]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Where does the 4095/4096 come from?  It is correct, but it seems to be a very strange way to represent the result.

```
  Simplify[r - expr]
  (* 0 *)
```

Doing `Expand` in *Mathematica*, instead of `TrigExpand` actually gives the expected result:

```
r = Expand[expr]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

From help, it says on `TrigExpand`:

> `TrigExpand` splits up sums and integer multiples that appear in arguments of trigonometric functions, and then expands out products of trigonometric functions into sums of powers, using trigonometric identities when possible.

The question is: Where did the `4095/4096` expression come from? (again, even though the result is correct mathematically, it looks strange, and I am just trying to understand the logic behind `4095/4096`.

Version 10.0.2 on Windows 7.

Comment: I have no idea where the 4096 comes from, but Simplify[r] gives your desired answer.

Comment: `TrigExpand` seems prone to producing strange results, when products of trig functions are involved.  See, for instance, my [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65179/trigexpand-idiosyncracies) on the subject.

Comment: Undesirable (to my mind) results occur for `TrigExpand[Cos[x]^(n + m) (1 - Cos[x]^2 + Sin[x])]`, where `m` is any integer.  For `m < 0`, results are similar to that in the Question.  `TrigExpand` exhibits greater creativity for `m > 0`.

Comment: The diligent & determined user could probably figure out what's happening from the nearly 3000 lists in the list `Trace[TrigExpand[expr], TraceInternal -> True]`.  That's certainly a lot of clues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is only a partial answer, but I believe the following observations might illuminate things somewhat.

Some background: recall that `TrigExpand[]` and ilk grew out of packages written by Maeder for his book *Programming in Mathematica*, and the old package `` Algebra`Trigonometry`​​ ``. I was familiar with how things were set up then before these functions were moved to the kernel, so I suspected the observation in the OP had something to do with the application of `ReplaceAll[]` being constrained (since there aren't any actual integer powers present). It took a bit to figure out to coax `TracePrint[]` to just show the interesting parts:

```
TracePrint[TrigExpand[Cos[x]^(n - 2) (1 - Cos[x]^2 + Sin[x])], 
           ReplaceAll[expr_, HoldPattern[Integrate`FakeIntervalElement[_] :> _]] /; 
           FreeQ[expr, _Complex] && ! FreeQ[expr, Sin | Cos], 
           TraceInternal -> True]
```

[image: dump of TrigExpand's trace]

Apparently, the rule for expanding out powers is applied with a hard limit (which I could not find from the output of `Trace[]`), so that the halving (note the sequence of powers of $2$ in the denominators) does not go on indefinitely.